# Moses Server Installation failed , Sudo command didn't work

Tags: ubuntu, rpc

I have installed Moses successfully in my Ubuntu OS. So i want to install Moses server to do xml rpc call to create an translation interface but i couldn't find any way how to do i install the Moses server in my PC and to do xml rpc call. I have also 250 Corpora in my own language. I have also followed the Moses manual but i don't find more useful to my work.

I have already tried this Linux command but it doesn't work properly.

```
Command-: sudo apt-get install libxmlrpc-core-c3
```

What error i got ?

> Reading package lists... Done Building dependency tree Reading state
>   information... Done libxmlrpc-core-c3 is already the newest version.
>   The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer
>   required: libkrb5-3:i386 libatk1.0-0:i386 libk5crypto3:i386
>   libstdc++6:i386
>
> libxfixes3:i386 libboost-filesystem1.46.1 libtorque2
>   libxcomposite1:i386
>
> libv4l-0:i386 libexpat1-dev libjpeg-turbo8:i386 libjpeg8:i386
>
> libboost-graph-parallel1.46.1 libxxf86vm1:i386 libboost-system1.46.1
>
> libxcb-glx0:i386 firefox-globalmenu libboost-python1.46.1
>
> libboost-signals1.46.1 libboost-program-options1.46.1 python-dev
>
> libcairo2:i386 libx11-xcb1:i386 libgnutls26:i386
>   libboost-date-time1.46.1
>
> libboost-test1.46.1 libtasn1-3:i386 libfreetype6:i386
>
> libboost-iostreams1.46.1 libopenmpi-dev libexpat1:i386
>   libv4lconvert0:i386
>
> libboost-wave1.46.1 libboost-graph1.46.1 libdatrie1:i386
>
> libavahi-common-data:i386 libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0:i386 libxcb1:i386
>
> libp11-kit0:i386 libxau6:i386 libpixman-1-0:i386 libcups2:i386
>
> libxinerama1:i386 libkrb5support0:i386 libxft2:i386 libssl-dev
>   libopenmpi1.3
>
> libssl-doc libice6:i386 libxdmcp6:i386 libgcrypt11:i386 libthai0:i386
>
> libkeyutils1:i386 libboost-thread1.46.1 libasound2:i386
>   libxrender1:i386
>
> libnuma1 libtiff4:i386 libjasper1:i386 gccxml libboost-mpi1.46.1
>   libibverbs1
>
> libavahi-client3:i386 libx11-6:i386 libfontconfig1:i386 libibverbs-dev
>
> libpango1.0-0:i386 libsm6:i386 libxdamage1:i386 libxcb-render0:i386
>
> libboost-math1.46.1 libgssapi-krb5-2:i386 libxi6:i386 python2.7-dev
>
> libxcursor1:i386 libxcb-shm0:i386 mpi-default-dev libxt6:i386
>   libxext6:i386
>
> libavahi-common3:i386 libboost-regex1.46.1 libxrandr2:i386
>   openmpi-common
>
> libgtk2.0-0:i386 libgpg-error0:i386 libllvm3.0 libllvm3.0:i386
>
> Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
>
> 0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 55 not upgraded.

So please help me out how should i install Moses server & xml-rpc in my PC and how can i use it ?

Comment: That's not an error, that says it installed correctly. It *also* says that there are a bunch of packages that you didn't explicitly install which are no longer being used, and you might look into removing them.

Comment: SO what to do then ........

Answer (score 1):

Now

```
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

will tiny up your system as it adviced at end of your result.

That's it.

about your result lines:

```
Reading package lists... Done Building dependency tree Reading state information... Done libxmlrpc-core-c3 is already the newest version. The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required: libkrb5-3:i386 libatk1.0-0:i386 libk5crypto3:i386 libstdc++6:i386
```

means nothing is to do.

then you got:

```
libxfixes3:i386 libboost-filesystem1.46.1 libtorque2 libxcomposite1:i386
libv4l-0:i386 libexpat1-dev libjpeg-turbo8:i386 libjpeg8:i386
(...)
libavahi-common3:i386 libboost-regex1.46.1 libxrandr2:i386 openmpi-common
libgtk2.0-0:i386 libgpg-error0:i386 libllvm3.0 libllvm3.0:i386
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
```

means *I don't need those packages any more*. But system does not decide to clean up itself. That's why you should run `autoremove` to process.

and that's finish by:

```
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 55 not upgraded.
```

it is what system did this time.